# Realm database: synchronization with server

Tags: xamarin.android, realm

I'm testing Realm database using test application RealmTasks and found out that synchronization with the server doesn't work. Authentication works well, but sync not. Realm server is installed on CentOS 7 server. Default port 9080 is busy so I changed Realm server config file:

```
http:
    enable: true
    listen_address:'0.0.0.0'
    listen_port:6666
network:
    http:
      listen_address:'0.0.0.0'
      listen_port:27080
```

As a result I can connect to 27080 from outside but can not connect to port 6666. All ports are opened for outside connection. Does it possible that such a configuration doesn't allow to synchronize database?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

That config file is just wrong - if that's exactly what you have. The yaml is nested wrongly because your first `http` is not nested.

Experimenting with the Mac Developer Edition, here's a minimal working `configuration.yml` file:

`storage:
  root_path: 'root_dir'
auth:
  public_key_path: 'keys/token-signature.pub'
  private_key_path: 'keys/token-signature.key'
proxy:
  http:
    listen_address: '::'
    listen_port: 9666`

**Important** - it seems port numbers are constrained the [configuration documentation(https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#configuring-the-server) mentions the need to use 1024 or higher as the server doesn't run as root. I am not sure why I could not get 6666 to run although that is supposedly commonly used for IRC. Multiple failure messages appear in the Terminal window of the process launching the server with that port.

**Earlier questions**

Are you telling the RealmTasks app to connect to that port? (Obvious question but I had to ask.)

Please supply logs from the server or look at the logs, which you can view and adjust the level of in the web dashboard eg at http://localhost:9080/#!/logs

Comment: I have the following situation: application can  connect to the server via 27080 port, database on server side was created but the application can not write any data to it. In log file using "info" level I see only messages about wrong password or login when I deliberately change it. By the way yesterday I installed Realms Object Server to the DigitalOcean virtual machine with default parameters and all is working normally there? all my applications are able to sync. So I think, that the problem with my changes in config file but I don't understand what is wron there